# Getting the data constructor name as a string using GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc

I'd like something like the following:

```
constrName :: Data a=> a -> String
constrName = showConstr . toConstr
```

But for `GHC.Generics`. I see the `Constructor` class, but don't see any instances in scope. I'm using `base-4.8.1.0`.

Comment: What do the `Rep` types look like for those? You are actually deriving `Generic` for them, right?

Comment: Side note: it looks like `t` is supposed to be a proxy of your choice; no need for `undefined`

Comment: @dfeur yeah the last issue was I just didn't derive the Generic instance :/ I've added a working answer and edited the question so the Q and A are both clearer

Answer (score 12):

Adapting this gist by Nathan Howell: https://gist.github.com/NathanHowell/6201625 :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.Generics

constrName :: (HasConstructor (Rep a), Generic a)=> a -> String
constrName = genericConstrName . from 

class HasConstructor (f :: * -> *) where
  genericConstrName :: f x -> String

instance HasConstructor f => HasConstructor (D1 c f) where
  genericConstrName (M1 x) = genericConstrName x

instance (HasConstructor x, HasConstructor y) => HasConstructor (x :+: y) where
  genericConstrName (L1 l) = genericConstrName l
  genericConstrName (R1 r) = genericConstrName r

instance Constructor c => HasConstructor (C1 c f) where
  genericConstrName x = conName x

--------------
data Foo = Bar Int | Baz Float deriving Generic
newtype X = X Char deriving Generic
data Y = Y deriving Generic
```

We can do:

```
*Main> constrName (Bar 1)
"Bar"
*Main> constrName $ X 'a'
"X"
*Main> constrName Y
"Y"
```