# How to write the instance for Show of a given datatype shorter?

Tags: haskell

I´m quite new to Haskell but I wonder how I can write following Code shorter:

```
data Suite = Club | Heart | Spade | Diamond 

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | 
King | Ace

data Card = Card Suite Value

instance Show Suite where
    show Club = "Club"
    show Heart = "Heart"
    show Spade = "Spade"
    show Diamond = "Diamond"

instance Enum Suite where
    enumFromTo Club Diamond = [Club, Heart, Spade, Diamond]
    enumFromTo Heart Diamond = [Heart, Spade, Diamond]
    enumFromTo Club Spade = [Club, Heart, Spade]

instance Show Value where
    show Two = "Two"
    show Three = "Three"
    show Four = "Four"
    show Five = "Five"
    show Six = "Six"
    show Seven = "Seven"
    show Eight = "Eight"
    show Nine = "Nine"
    show Ten = "Ten"
    show Jack = "Jack"
    show Queen = "Queen"
    show King = "King"
    show Ace = "Ace"
```

I want to write the instance for **Show Value** way shorter. Is there a good way to do this or do I need to write all of it?
I also wonder how i could go from here if I want to define the same instances for Eq Card, Ord Card?
So far

```
instance Eq Card where
    Card _ _ == _ = False

instance Ord Card where
    Card Heart Three > Card Heart Two = True
```

worked, but to write every single possibility would be quite a lot of work.
Thanks for any answers!

Edit: I´m aware of the possiblity to append deriving (Show, etc..) but I don´t want to use it

Comment: Exactly why don't you want to use `deriving`?

Comment: Just tossing `deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)` on `Card` would solve it nicely.

Comment: `deriving` is exactly to save a lot of work, avoid making mistakes, and for some type classes, it is the only instance allowed for *Safe Haskell*.

Comment: To get to know haskell little bit better

Comment: You can make use of `Generic`s to derive the constructor name, but that will result in some extra (and quite complicated) logic.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179380/getting-the-data-constructor-name-as-a-string-using-ghc-generics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've rejected `deriving` these instances, which is the main way we avoid that much boilerplate. The most obvious remaining elementary way to shorten the `Show Value` is to use a `case` expression. This uses an extra line but shortens each case slightly:

```
instance Show Value where
    show x = case x of
      Two -> "Two"
      Three -> "Three"
      -- etc.
```

Expanding to non-elementary ways, you could

1. Use generics, either the somewhat more modern version in `GHC.Generics` or (probably easier in this case) the one in `Data.Data`. For these, you'll need `deriving Generic` or `deriving Data`, respectively, and then you can write (or dig up on Hackage) generic versions of the class methods you need. Neither of these approaches seems very appropriate for a Haskell beginner, but you can work up to them over a number of months.
2. Use Template Haskell. This is a very advanced language feature, and despite working with Haskell for many years, I have not really begun to grasp how to program with it. Good luck!

Comment: I'd say Template Haskell is not so much a very advanced feature as just tedious, unsafe and pretty un-idiomatic – Haskell's “hey, we can do what Lisp can too!” hack. Generics are more advanced, somewhat less tedious (still _rather_ tedious), but much safer and more idiomatic.

Comment: For someone who, to quote OP, is trying "to get to know Haskell [a] little bit better," I can't in good faith suggest Template Haskell _or_ generics.

Comment: @AndrewRay, my sentiment exactly. Learn how to write them by hand the boring way, then derive them whenever possible.

Comment: @leftaroundabout can you recommend a reasonably up-to-date Template Haskell tutorial?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want your `show` method call to print the name of the constructor (as it appears here), there's no need to manually instance them at all. You can automatically derive the `Show` instance thusly:

```
data Suit = Club | Heart | Spade | Diamond
    deriving Show

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven 
    | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
    deriving Show
```

Comment: `Enum` can be derived too.

Answer (score 2):

In *some* cases, such as `Instance Show Value`, there is no good way to shorten it without `deriving` (not counting the ones in dfeuer's answer).

But in others there is! E.g.

1. for the `Enum` instances it's enough to define `fromEnum` and `toEnum`, all the rest have default definitions. You certainly don't need to list all possibilities in `enumFromTo` as your example code does.
2. After you define `instance Enum Value`, you can write comparison functions by converting to `Int` and comparing the results:

   ```
   instance Eq Value where
     x == y = fromEnum x == fromEnum y

   instance Ord Value where
     compare x y = compare (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y)
   ```
3. You can use instances for `Value` and `Suit` when writing definitions for `Card`, e.g.

   ```
   instance Eq Card where
     Card s1 v1 == Card s2 v2 = s1 == s2 && v1 == v2
   ```